# Error for trying to get crypto price. Getting key error

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to get make a request to the Coin Market Cap API, but the code did not work. I am getting a KeyError in the return statement.

Here is my code.

```
#Description: Get the current price of Bitcoin

#Import the requests library
import requests

    TICKER_API_URL = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/'
    
    def get_latest_crypto_price(crypto):
      
      response = requests.get(TICKER_API_URL+crypto)
      response_json = response.json()
      
      return float(response_json[0]['price_usd'])
    
get_latest_crypto_price('bitcoin')
```

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin is no longer an endpoint. Your full response is:

```
{'code': '410 Gone', 'reason': 'We no longer serving this endpoint here'}
```

It seems like they have migrated to a [different endpoint](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#section/Endpoint-Overview).

The reason you get a key error is that you expected to get a list of values; however since they have migrated you do not get an array, you get a json object with the error noted above.

Comment: How can i get throught this while getting my program done. the program is to tracker live prices of bitcoin

Comment: You need to update your URL and add a API key to a header when sending the request. See [here](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/) for a quick guide.